# Recursive conditional types in 4.1.0-dev fail when trying to type `pipe`

Tags: typescript

I am really excited for 4.1.0 and recursive conditional types, as they can remove the long walls of function overloads. I tried with `Object.assign` and it worked well, but I must have been doing something wrong with `pipe`. This is what I have tried so far:

```js
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer U, ...any[]] ? U : never;
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => void) extends (head: any, ...tail: infer U) => any ? U : never;

type PipeChain<I, B extends Array<(arg: any) => any>, A extends Array<(arg: any) => any> = []> = B['length'] extends 0 ? I : Head<B> extends (arg: I) => infer O ? PipeChain<O, Tail<B>, [...A, Head<B>]> : never

type d = PipeChain<'a', [(arg: 'a') => 'b', (arg: 'b') => 'c', (arg: 'c') => 'd']>

function pipe<FN extends (...args: any[]) => any, FNS extends Array<(arg: any) => any>, R extends PipeChain<ReturnType<FN>, FNS>>(fn: FN, ...fns: FNS): (...args: Parameters<FN>) => R {
    return (...args) => fns.reduce((val, fn) => fn(val), fn(...args))
}

const ff = pipe(
    (a:number) => Math.pow(a, 3),
    (a) => `${a}`,
    (a) => a.length
)
```

The pipe usage triggers the following error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201011#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATAPAFShAHsCA7RAzlPLiANoC6AfFALxTpY75FkCWuAZhAE5QCqAGigA6MSXIUKUAPwCoALii4IAN14BuAFChIDeGwA2aDNjyFipSjXoAKW2JHweAcwJLUASjo1VAezZEbyZzIlsACwREJQlhR2ADQyUObj5+b1oaCVl5JRV1Hm0dcGgABTZIAGFwg1xkAElhACFTZgsAQR4eeBBkW2cXGNIMrNIqYXbW0KhO7t7+1yGQEcsQGyhrOigmsgByQzwXYHDd6RCWKAAGHPrFWCjkJppziwXBqHqVlN4oAHkc8pVGocZC-YSoRKPcYbRztYRwJBQ6h3fK8LTFPSILaAiDVWrIXbwXbCMhvJSE3YrXYAI2JUDJUBplJ8jIAxnSGbt2VTEKcqOjOABXXCs4BsPy4KBgCoQZAAMQAclMLg5xK53KtKCtYlBFQBlZUdLo9PoDJbasbCABKhqIOLxIKtEGAgp4uFQJXlCuh+qoVFsnFwSkVcTEgY1+s8SlVTnVSlKzngAFtnbwCF6qCsbQBvLRQfNQHjO12SmMDAgrcMiIuIQWsiD2VTwQzCQOV3C2JuGTytjuOcueTxaAC+6NZEoIwCgnE4W2lkFseYL-QUuEFSepvBWAFl4McRGA-AB3frCADMPaX+f6KwABgASbPwYe3wRX+nwbUiA64I7hLSeEAA)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question*, as well as any off-site links.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have a link to the playground?

Comment: Yes, I can see that, note I said *"in the question"* and *"**as well as** any off-site links"*